# How to select a datapoint in a XamarinForms.Microchart

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, linechart

I am learning Xamarin and have added the Microcharts nuget package then added a LineChart to my page and populated with my data and looks great.

I'm looking for documentation on how I can make the chart "interactive", so say if a user touches a datapoint that has label of "2012-01-01" I could grab that in the Touched event and perform a query to retrieve my records for that day?

Can this be easily achieved and if so can you point me to docs for it or advise how? If not can you recommend any better charting packages that I might be better to look at?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see [in this issue](https://github.com/dotnet-ad/Microcharts/issues/103) this is not supported as of now.

I found that charting is a bit of a sore spot in Xamarin Forms. At least if you are limited to Open Source / Non-Commercial. From what I see Oxyplot might have some interaction options though: [See the documentation here](https://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/controllers/index.html?highlight=click#default-input-bindings).

Also Syncfusion has chart controls and under certain conditions you can apply for a free license. [See here](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense).